# Safari doesn't update SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple form to update a row in my database and also have a language link/button. SUBMIT button works and writes values to my database. However after I click the link button twice (to go back the same page) I see the old value in the text box. I refresh the page and then I see updated value. It works on Chrome without any problems but somehow Safari caches the database values and doesn't refresh.

Here is my code:

```
// Get language
if (isset($_GET['language']))
{
  $get_lang = $_GET['language'];

  if ($get_lang == 'fr') {
      $lang_code = 'fr';
  }
  else if ($get_lang == 'en') {
      $lang_code = 'en';
  }
  else {
      $lang_code = 'fr';
  }
}
else
{
  $php_self = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
  header("refresh:0; url=$php_self?language=en");
  $lang_code = 'en';
}

include('../inc/config.php');
include('inc/head.php');

global $db;


// Update page
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) )
{

  $lang_code        = $_GET['language'];
  $page_title       = $_POST['page_title'];

  if ( $lang_code == 'fr' )
  {
    $updatePage = $db->execute("UPDATE pages SET page_title_fr=? WHERE page_id=1", array($page_title));

  }
  else if ( $lang_code == 'en' )
  {
    $updatePage = $db->execute("UPDATE pages SET page_title_en=? WHERE page_id=1", array($page_title);
  }

}


// Get page content
$page_content = $db->get_row("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page_id = 1" );

if ( $lang_code == 'fr' )
{  
  $page_title       = $page_content->page_title_fr;
}
else
{
  $page_title       = $page_content->page_title_en;
}
```

and my form :

```
// Button for changing the language
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?language=<?php if ( $lang_code == 'fr' ) { echo 'en'; } else if ( $lang_code == 'en' ) { echo 'fr'; } ?>"><?php if ( $lang_code == 'en' ) { echo 'FRENCH'; } else { echo 'ENGLISH'; } ?></a>


<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?language=<?php echo $lang_code; ?>">

<input name="page_title" type="text" value="<?php echo $page_title; ?>">

<button name="submit" type="submit">SAVE</button>

</form>
```

EDIT : I've tried disabling caching but it didn't help.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

EDIT 2 : Disabling the cache from Safari's Develop menu fixes the problem

Comment: Would it not make sense to first see how you tell the browser not to cache the page?

Comment: Do you think it should cache the "$page_title" ? I am getting it from my database and only Safari caches it, Chrome doesn't

Comment: Check this to reduce caching: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers

Comment: I've tried disabling caching but it didn't help

Comment: You are not showing us how you disabled caching. It is not very likely that the PHP code has an error: PHP is not depending on the browser.

Comment: Ok I updated my code

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding these lines to my htaccess file

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|php)$">
FileETag None
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
```